# retrieve multiple data to list view?

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am trying to retrieve multiple data from multiple row... i have found this code and getting some result that i am not understanding. can anyone check and tell me if it is correct or not and later i want to show these multiple result into listview inside android app... is it correct for that too?

For testing, I am running this code using postman and getting this result [Screen Shot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vt7r1ki9a8u1gsy/SS.png?dl=0)

here you can check my php codes:

My DbOperations.php

```
public function gettestuser($pin, $a, $b, $ho, $ll, $c, $d){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM test_category WHERE name = ? AND a = ? Or b = ? Or ho = ? Or ll = ? Or c = ? Or d = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss",$pin,$a,$b,$ho,$ll,$c,$d);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
}
```

My gettestuser.php

```
<?php
require_once '../include/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
if(isset($_POST['reg_pin'])){

$db = new DbOperations();

$test_category = $db->gettestuser($_POST['reg_pin'], $_POST['reg_a'], $_POST['reg_b'], $_POST['reg_ho'], $_POST['reg_ll'], $_POST['reg_c'], $_POST['reg_d']);

var_dump($test_category);

    $response['error'] = false;
    $response['pid'] = $test_category['pid'];
    $response['name'] = $test_category['name'];
    $response['pin'] = $test_category['pin'];
    $response['a'] = $test_category['a'];
    $response['b'] = $test_category['b'];
    $response['ho'] = $test_category['ho'];
    $response['ll'] = $test_category['ll'];
    $response['c'] = $test_category['c'];
    $response['d'] = $test_category['d'];

}else{
$response['error'] = true;
$response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
}
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: When using ANDs and ORs, an astute use of parentheses is required

Comment: @Strawberry i didn't get it, can you explain it more?

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

Here's an example of a query that uses parentheses...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM test_category 
 WHERE name = ? 
   AND (a = ? Or b = ?) 
    OR (ho = ? Or ll = ?) 
    OR (c = ? Or d = ?);
```

Comment: Did you check the screen shot?

Comment: @sumitpal No. I don't do screenshots. If one month on, you're still struggling with this, I suggest you see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: no... actually i was busy in my college exams... so i didn't get time to check it, just started today to work further... anyways can you just check the screen shot and tell me if my code it right or where is the mistake? and I'll also try your method and let you know if it works. Thank You.